# Can't resize Partition (Plus Button Grayed Out)

Tags: gparted, disk-usage, disk-management

i only allocated 20 GB for linux and now my linux home directory almost full , and i want to resize it.
im now in live usb but i cant resize the partition
what should i do?

[image]
 **<sup>Click image to enlarge</sup>**

[image]
 **<sup>Click image to enlarge</sup>**

Comment: You need to shrink the partition to the left first, then move to the left and finally resize. Since you'll be shrinking a Windows partition do it from Windows and only then boot the live session again.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks do you mean i have to shrink windows partition from window? is it safe?

Comment: Yes, it is safe and better to do it from Windows with Windows tools so Windows can adjust for the new size immediately.